# Ajax Jquery throws 404 not found some times

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Im making an CRUD page on ASP.NET MVC using bootstrap. My problem is when I´m loading a differents records, and trying to update. With some records works fine, and with others don´t. I´m getting de 404 Not found error.

Im using the same Action for insert or update. The fields are all strings. 
At first I was using the jquery serialize() function to get the values of the form.

```
    function InsertButtonEvent() {

    var formvalues = $('#filialForm').serialize();


    $.blockUI({ message: '<h1>Un momento por favor..</h1>' });
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '../CatFiliales/InsertItem',
        data: formvalues,
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptionx, thrownError) {
            swal('error', xhr.status + ' ' + thrownError, 'error');
            $.unblockUI();
        }
    })
   .done(function (htmlPartialView) {
       swal('', 'Registro Insertado', 'success');
       renderPartialView(htmlPartialView);

   });
```

Comparing the form values to be post, a few variables were missing. So, I force to send the same variables (even without data). And the result still being the same, some times I can hit the controller method and some times I get the 404 Not Found Error.

```
function InsertButtonEvent() {
    var edo = $('#cmbEstadoLegal').val();
    var formvalues = $('#filialForm').serialize();
    var txtClaveFilialjq =  $('#txtClaveFilial').val();  
    var txtDescripcionBrevejq = $('#txtDescripcionBreve ').val(); 
    var txtDescripcionjq = $('#txtDescripcion').val(); 
    var txtIdFiscaljq = $('#txtIdFiscal').val(); 
    var txtNodoFilialjq= $('#txtNodoFilial ').val();
    var cmbEstadojq = $('#cmbEstado').val(); 
    var cmbParticipacionAccionariajq= $('#cmbParticipacionAccionaria').val(); 
    var cmbCveEdoOperjq = $('#cmbCveEdoOper').val(); 
    var cmbGiroFilialjq=  $('#cmbGiroFilial').val(); 
    var cmbGrupoFilialesjq= $('#cmbGrupoFiliales').val(); 
    var cmbParaestataljq= $('#cmbParaestatal').val(); 
    var cmbTipoEmpresajq= $('#cmbTipoEmpresa').val();
    var cmbEstadoLegaljq= $('#cmbEstadoLegal').val(); 
    var txtFecConstitjq =  $('#txtFecConstit').val(); 
    var cmbMonedaNormalizadajq = $('#cmbMonedaNormalizada ').val();  
    var cmbMonedasAccionesjq = $('#cmbMonedasAcciones').val(); 
    var txtValorContableAccionesjq =   $('#txtValorContableAcciones').val(); 
    var txtFecValAccionesjq= $('#txtFecValAcciones').val(); 
    var txtDomiciliojq = $('#txtDomicilio').val(); 
    var txtSitioWebFinaljq =  $('#txtSitioWebFinal').val(); 
    var txtTelefonojq=  $('#txtTelefono').val(); 
    var txtNumTeleFaxjq= $('#txtNumTeleFax').val(); 
    var cmbPaisjq= $('#cmbPais').val();  
    var cmbResidenciasjq =  $('#cmbResidencias').val();  
    var cmbNacionalidadesjq =  $('#cmbNacionalidades').val(); 
    var txtObjetivojq =  $('#txtObjetivo').val(); 
    var txtObservacionesjq = $('#txtObservaciones').val();


    $.blockUI({ message: '<h1>Un momento por favor..</h1>' });
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '../CatFiliales/InsertItem',
        data: {
            txtClaveFilial : txtClaveFilialjq ,  
            txtDescripcionBreve  :  txtDescripcionBrevejq , 
            txtDescripcion  :  txtDescripcionjq, 
            txtIdFiscal  : txtIdFiscaljq , 
            txtNodoFilial  : txtNodoFilialjq ,
            cmbEstado  : cmbEstadojq , 
            cmbParticipacionAccionaria  :  cmbParticipacionAccionariajq    , 
            cmbCveEdoOper  : cmbCveEdoOperjq , 
            cmbGiroFilial  : cmbGiroFilialjq , 
            cmbGrupoFiliales  : cmbGrupoFilialesjq , 
            cmbParaestatal  : cmbParaestataljq , 
            cmbTipoEmpresa  : cmbTipoEmpresajq ,
            cmbEstadoLegal : cmbEstadoLegaljq , 
            txtFecConstit  :   txtFecConstitjq , 
            cmbMonedaNormalizada  : cmbMonedaNormalizadajq,  
            cmbMonedasAcciones  :  cmbMonedasAccionesjq , 
            txtValorContableAcciones  : txtValorContableAccionesjq , 
            txtFecValAcciones  : txtFecValAccionesjq , 
            txtDomicilio  : txtDomiciliojq , 
            txtSitioWebFinal  : txtSitioWebFinaljq, 
            txtTelefono  : txtTelefonojq, 
            txtNumTeleFax : txtNumTeleFaxjq , 
            cmbPais  :  cmbPaisjq ,  
            cmbResidencias  :cmbResidenciasjq,  
            cmbNacionalidades  :cmbNacionalidadesjq , 
            txtObjetivo: txtObjetivojq,
            txtObservaciones: txtObservacionesjq

        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptionx, thrownError) {
            swal('error', xhr.status + ' ' + thrownError, 'error');
            $.unblockUI();
        }
    })
   .done(function (htmlPartialView) {
       swal('', 'Registro Insertado', 'success');
       renderPartialView(htmlPartialView);

   });
```

Here is my controller code

```
public ActionResult InsertItem(
        string  txtClaveFilial,  
        string  txtDescripcionBreve , 
        string  txtDescripcion , 
        string  txtIdFiscal , 
        string  txtNodoFilial ,
        string  cmbEstado , 
        string  cmbParticipacionAccionaria , 
        string  cmbCveEdoOper , 
        string  cmbGiroFilial , 
        string  cmbGrupoFiliales , 
        string  cmbParaestatal , 
        string cmbTipoEmpresa ,
        string  cmbEstadoLegal, 
        string  txtFecConstit , 
        string  cmbMonedaNormalizada ,  
        string  cmbMonedasAcciones , 
        string  txtValorContableAcciones , 
        string  txtFecValAcciones , 
        string  txtDomicilio , 
        string  txtSitioWebFinal , 
        string  txtTelefono , 
        string  txtNumTeleFax , 
        string  cmbPais ,  
        string  cmbResidencias ,  
        string  cmbNacionalidades , 
        string  txtObjetivo , 
        string  txtObservaciones


          )
        {

//Do all the stuff with variables;


            return PartialView("_Registers", catFilialesViewModel.Filiales);
        }
```

I think that the error is because sometimes is not sending all the parameters to the method. But, why doesn´t work even when I'm setting all the parameters?

Thanks a lot

Comment: `Im using the same Action for insert or update` ...whyyyy!!!

Comment: Because I don´t want to add logic in jquery code. Instead I do the logic inside the controller.

Comment: Also, when you do CRUD operations it's better to use `post` instead of `get`....you should use get just for retrieving info and stuffs like that...also you could use a break point in your insert item method in order to better konw the actual cause of the 404 response...usa puntos de interrupción para depurar la llamada al método, debe estar fallando alguna validación que hace que no retorne nada.

Comment: The reason I'm using Post is because Im retrieving a partial view after the update-insert operation, and refreshing a section in the page with the "new" data. All in the same page.  Inside the breakpoints all the parameters are filled. Just dont know why in some cases I can hit the controller and anothers get the 404 Not found error.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I tried the controller action with few parameters.
Found that the last two where a lot of text. It might happened that some character makes the sent values different.

AS Hackerman said, is Better with post instead GET.. I tried and worked ok.

Thanks a lot